# Get element from List if exists

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get 2 first values from list and store them in two variables. If list contains >= 2 values I should set `variable1` and `variable2`, but if values list is shorter I should get `null` as `variable1` and/or `variable2`.

I'm now stuck with this code:

```
var variable1 = values.Take(1).FirstOrDefault(); // I know it can be just FirstOrDefault()
var variable2 = values.Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

But this looks kinda hacky. Is there any cleaner way to get it? Something like:

```
var variable1 = values.TakeOrDefault(0); //getting first element or default
var variable2 = values.TakeOrDefault(1); //getting second element or default
```

Comment: You could write an extension method that does the work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just after @StepUp answer I found out that it actually can be achieved using built in function `ElementAtOrDefault` which is exactly what I was looking for:

```
var variable1 = values.ElementAtOrDefault(0); //getting first element or default
var variable2 = values.ElementAtOrDefault(1); //getting second element or default
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not create an extension method?

This is just a standard implementation which iterates over the enumerable. If it hits an item twice, it returns the item. Else it returns the default.

```
public static T SecondOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    IEnumerator<T> i = list.GetEnumerator();

    if (i.MoveNext() && i.MoveNext())
    {
        return i.Current;
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

Or maybe you like this more generic approach better?

```
public static T NthOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int n)
{
    IEnumerator<T> i = list.GetEnumerator();

    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
    {
        if (!i.MoveNext())
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return i.Current;
}
```

It trusts `IEnumerable<T>` to return `default(T)` if there is no current, so it will not throw any exceptions. If you want to, you can always safeguard it more.

Comment: I think I'll go with the `NthOrDefault` extension method. I was hoping there is such magic way to do this without extension method :) Thanks

Comment: I found `ElementAtOrDefault` from `Enumerable` and I think it perfectly matches my expectations. Nevertheless thanks for help :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I know that solution is given, but I would like to show another one.
If you want just take the first two items from list, you can do it like this:

```
int[] someArray = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};                
int a,b;
int[] newArray = someArray.Where((e, i) => i <=1).ToArray();
if (newArray.ElementAtOrDefault(0) != null)       
   a = newArray[0];
if(newArray.ElementAtOrDefault(1)!=null)
   b= newArray[1];
```